# How can I vertically scroll a UI-grid using selenium web driver?

Tags: java, user-interface, selenium, scroll

I need to focus on a button in the UI grid for which I need to scroll vertically within the grid (not the browser scroll). Please help in doing this using selenium web driver (java)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First hover the mouse on that particular grid you wanted to scroll.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("..........."));
action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("............"))).click().build().perform();
```

Then scroll that grid using...

Please try the following code...

```
if(driver instanceOf JavaScriptExecutor){
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,250);");
}
```

This will scroll down vertically.